# SharePoint 2007 licensing question

Tags: sharepoint-2007, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I've SharePoint 2007 Enterprise installed. I recently found out I have

1. 10 licenses for SharePoint 2007 Enterprise CAL
2. 40 licenses for SharePoint 2007 Standard CAL

Does it mean 50 people can use SharePoint or how licensing works in this case?

Just for sake of all information, i was  given that system and licenses just wanted to be clear what correct licensing should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50 people can use the Sharepoint, and 10 of those people are allow to use the Enterprise features...

Comment: How could I enforce proper licensing usage then. Enterprise features are enabled everywhere and everyone can use it?

Comment: make a site that enables Enterprise features and only allow 10 people into the site, and the rest of the sites diable Ent. features and all 50 people can access. You can disable the Enterprise feature through the site collection settings.